# Java analogue to Kotlins .copy() functon

Tags: java, kotlin, immutability

I'm working with an immutable data-structure in Java and am getting mildly annoyed, by the tedious work of copying each object when I want to change the properties of them.

I know in **Kotlin** this can be done easily with the data-classes `.copy()` function. And I want to know if there is the same function in **Java**? Maybe over some library?

Something that would allow stuff like this:

**Implementation:**

```
fun copy(name: String = this.name, age: Int = this.age) = User(name, age)
```

**Usage:**

```
val jack = User(name = "Jack", age = 1)
val olderJack = jack.copy(age = 2)
```

Thanks for your help ^^

Comment: Nope, there's nothing with that black magic power in java... Unfortunately :*(

You have to create your helpers methods / utilities by hand, there's nothing by design that do that.

Comment: You can also generate those, e.g. with your IDE's template generator. But do not forget to regenerate if fields change! (similar to generated `toString`, `equals`, `hashCode` etc.) ... and don't forget, that you can actually write the `data class` in Kotlin and just use it in Java...